# iptables / ebtables hook function to filter on interface or layer 2

Tags: linux-kernel, netfilter, ebtables

I have used netfilter hook functions to filter/sniff on outgoing IP packets. I'm looking to filter outgoing (from host) packets between IP layer and Link layer to look into Layer 2 information like - interface, MAC address. The NF_INET_POSTROUTING does not give mac address information as it is called in ip_output() before address resolution i guess.

I looked up ebtables hook functions, they seem to be related to Bridge INPUT/FORWARD/OUTPUT. If i understand, the outgoing packets from local tcp/ip do not go through bridge forwarding hooks. Is there way i can hook into packets between Linux IP and link layer to filter (DROP or modify) ...?

Comment: I'm writing this as kernel mod driver. I may forward some packets to user space and prevent it going out on NIC. So, i really cant use iptable/ebtables commands since i need sk_buffer data. I need the full  frame - eth, IP headers.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there's a generic way to hook this, but some methods come to mind:

- `LD_PRELOAD` socket operations: Supply a shared library with your own implementation of `send(|to|msg)`
- Register a virtual TAP interface and have your application bind to it
- Register a virtual interface in-kernel and have your application bind to it

The [bonding](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/net/bonding/bond_main.c) driver is an example of the latter. Behind the scenes, it scatters egress traffic to slave devices and gathers ingress traffic from them.

I tried this in my [uman](https://github.com/a3f/uman) driver. You can configure via DebugFS an interface to micro-manage. Any application binding to the `uman0` virtual interface will have its egress traffic pass through `uman_start_xmit` and ingress traffic via `uman_handle_frame`, where you can add code to decide whether to forward/mangle/drop the packet. `uman` was a side product of my bachelor thesis and might not be fit for production use (If you make it fitter, pull requests are welcome :-).